# Setting disableCNCheck using Grails Cxf Client Plugin

Tags: web-services, grails, https, cxf, grails-plugin

I'm trying to set disableCNCheck to true for my web service.  I'm using Grails 2.2.0 with the Cxf Client plugin.

I found this question:
[wsdl2java CXF command line error about disableCNCheck option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874039/wsdl2java-cxf-command-line-error-about-disablecncheck-option)

with this piece of code:

```
protected void disableCNCheck(Object port) {
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port)

    TLSClientParameters params = new TLSClientParameters()
    params.setDisableCNCheck(true)
    HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client?.getConduit()
    httpConduit?.setTlsClientParameters(params)
}
```

In which class would this code belong and where would the method be called?  Is there a configuration parameter for the Cxf Client plugin that I could set instead?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the code you can achieve the disableCNCheck by adding the below xml config to grails-app/conf/spring/resources.xml [ Grails 2.2.3 , cxf-client plugin 1.6.1

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
      "> 

  <http:conduit name="*.http-conduit"> 
    <http:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="true" /> 
  </http:conduit> 

</beans>
```